# In how many arrangements of the digits 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 in a row does the consecutive series 247 appear?

Tags: combinatorics

My solution is to take the series 247 as one body, then we have 5! permutations

but I could be extremely wrong.

is it correct?

and another extra question is in how many arrangements of the digits 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 in the line appears at least one of the following series: 24, 27 or 47? in which way i can approach this one?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The first is correct.  The second is similar, only now you have to count each case separately, taking care not to double count the strings in which both $24$ and $47$ appear.

Comment: For the "$24$, $27$, $47$"-part apply the inclusion-exclusion principle. (Or draw a Venn-Euler diagram for the corresponding sets of realizations, and look closer at the intersections.)

Answer (score 1):

For the second question:

We have $6!$ possibilities for each $24$, $27$ and $47$ as a group. So we have $3\times 6!$ possibilities in total.

But for the first case ($24$ as a group), in certain possibilities, $247$ will occur together. Similarly, for the third case($47$ as a group), $247$ will occur together in certain possibilities. Since $247$ is double-counted, we need to eliminate its set of possibilities once from the total.

Taking $247$ as a group, we have $5!$ possibilities.

So in total, we have

$$6!+6!+6!-5!$$ possibilities.

Thanks to @LightLamps and @JaapScherphuis for pointing out the mistakes I did

Comment: why exclude the possibility of getting 247 from the group 24? the question asked atleast one of 24,47 so it can't be both ?

Comment: @LightLamps I think you're right! I have misinterpreted the question

Comment: I think we 3 cases where we need to Exclude the possibilities of 24 to appear such that 7! is the all the possibilities , 7! - 6! and same for 47 and 27. and to be atleast one of those 3 to appear but mentioning that 24 and 27 + 27 and 47 can't appear simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think so... if we take 24 as a group, we have 5 of the remaining numbers and 1 group. So there are 6 elements in total.

Comment: i mean 7! for all possibilities to permute digits from 1 to 7 without restriction

Comment: If you remove the possibilities of getting a particular group (say 24) from all the possibilities(which is $7!$ in number), there is no guarantee that either one of the other groups (or both for that matter) would come. Example: 4267123

Comment: Also, 24 and 27 can't occur simultaneously because we would need two $2$'s for that! By doing permutations, we are rearranging the already existing set. We can't introduce duplicate numbers by that!

Comment: $24$ can be followed by a $7$ to get $247$, in that case there would be two groups existing simultaneously (namely, $24$ and $47$)

Comment: In your $3\cdot6!$ calculation, the arrangements with $247$ are double counted, so you have to subtract $5!$ once (but not twice since we do want to allow $247$).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  we have 3 cases, 1) only 47 appear 2) only 24 3) 24 and 47 together. so one of the 3 must appear atleast once. cant we find the possibilities for case 1 to find 47 series without 24 and case 2 findining all possibilities of 24 alone without 47 and case 3 is just 5!. then sum all 3 cases according to the sum principle then we can have atleast one of the 3 cases occur?

Comment: @LightLamps: Yes, so then you would get $(6!-5!)+(6!-5!)+5!+6!$, where the last $6!$ is the cases containing $27$. Whichever way you do it, the result is $3\cdot6!-5!$.

Comment: @LightLamps I'm sorry for the wrong interpretation of the question. I hope that you're not confused by it. I have edited my answer to make it clear.